# Calculating SHA1 hash of a 'nvarchar' string using T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, hash, nvarchar

I'm trying to calculate `SHA1` hash of a unicode string using T-SQL. The below code works fine with `ASCII` strings:

```
declare @input varchar(50)
set @input = 'some text'
print 'SHA1 Hash: ' + UPPER(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, HashBytes('SHA1', @input), 1, 0))
```

but it calculates wrong hash when I replace first line of code with `declare @input nvarchar(50)`.

```
Calculated hash (nvarchar): BBA91B680CE2685E9465DE24967E425CF055B10F
Calculated hash by a tool : 37AA63C77398D954473262E1A0057C1E632EDA77
```

How can I calculate `SHA1` hash of a `nvarchar` ?

[EDIT]:

Below C# code generate same hash as the tool I use for hashing:

```
// Computes SHA1 hash of a given string
string ComputeHash(string input)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    byte[] hash;
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetBytes(input);

    using (var sha = SHA1Managed.Create())
        hash = sha.ComputeHash(bytes);

    foreach (var b in hash)
        result += b.ToString("X2");

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure that the hash returned by your tool is using `UTF16` or Unicode encoding when you compare it with the one returned by SQL Server?...`SHA1` (and other encoding formats) depends on the data type, so it should return different values when given as an input. Take a look at [this](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2009/04/28/Comparing-SQL-Server-HASHBYTES-function-and-.Net-hashing.aspx) link for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks, useful link. It's a known bug with `HashBytes` as the article describes. Now I can understand why Microsoft is not so good at adopting to international standards; when two teams on the same company compute hash differently (SQL vs .NET) based on input **data-type**.

Comment: Actually it's not a bug, as the article states the difference is based on the data type you're passing in to HashBytes and the encoding you're using to convert strings to bytes in .net. Provided you use the same - e.g. use `nvarchar` and `Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-16").GetBytes(value)` OR use `varchar` and `Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8").GetBytes(value)` - then you should get the same result.